# Request to reopen an old question which I have edited

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen

[Identifying parallel and series capacitors for capacitor system with dieletric inserted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560429/)

The OP had posted this question with large images and lack of MathJax formatting. I have edited it and made it much more presentable. There is a very relevant and conceptual question at the end of the OP's text. If the community could help me reopen it, that'd be excellent. Thanks.

Comment: LaTeX? Do you mean [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax)?

Comment: I never understood the difference between the two haha @PeterMortensen

Comment: Honestly, if the goal is to edit this question into on-topicness, I think there's a whole lot of work left to do. If there is a relevant conceptual question somewhere in the post, starting with a screenshot of a problem set is not very convincing. That might be fine if it was OP editing, but if you want to rescue an old thread, there's much more to do there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your edit automatically enqueued the question for reopen review - it used to be the case that every first edit after closure did that, but the [recent changes to review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/263383) included the introduction of a checkbox with which you can mark your edit as significant enough to warrant reopen review. There is therefore no need to make separate meta posts about questions you have edited - just tick the box.

The [reopen review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/355892) you triggered concluded 3:0 unanimously with *leave closed*.